# How to create a customized paragraph?

Tags: indentation, paragraphs

In addition to numbered and unnumbered paragraphs (section, subsection, subsubsection) I would like to have in my thesis some indented and titled paragraphs, but as `paragraph` command doesn't meet my needs, I'm searching for another solution. Indeed, `paragraph` command doesn't put enough in light the part of the text I want to emphasize. 
That paragraph would begin by a title such as : "Observation 1" as in the following picture : [image] in which the paragraph that follows its title ("Observation 20") begins with an indentation different from the identation of the main body of the text.

Does anybody have a suggestion ? In the following mwe, I use an unnumbered `description` list in order to have an indented paragraph.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,footinclude=true,twoside,headinclude=true]{scrbook}
\usepackage[parts,pdfspacing,dottedtoc]{classicthesis}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[applemac]{inputenc}    
\usepackage[frenchb]{babel}
\setmainfont{Minion Pro}
    \usepackage[marginparsep=8pt,left=3.5cm,right=3.5cm,top=3cm,bottom=3cm]{geometry}


    \begin{document}

   \begin{description}
    This is my text
   \end{description}

    \end{document}
```

Comment: You've asked enough questions to know that you should include a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228), and that you have not given anything like enough information to help you. We don't know anything really - what class you are using, whether you've modified the behaviour of the sectioning commands or, in fact, in what way `\paragraph` fails to meet your needs. How can I suggest what might suit your needs without your telling me what those needs are?!

Comment: @ Down-voters Please don't vote down below -1. -1 is quite enough to show that the question needs improvement.

Comment: I've just added some improvments to my question.

Comment: That is better but please ***read the link I posted***. We want code which we can copy-paste-compile to see the problem. That code will not produce any output, let alone the output you want to change. Moreover, some of those packages are almost certainly of no relevance to your question. You want less preamble and more content! Like I said, please read the instructions provided at the link above as that explains exactly what you need to do to post an MWE which will enable people to help you. (For example, you surely need a `\paragraph...` somewhere and you surely don't need `graphicx`!

Comment: And we still have no idea what you are trying to do... I've removed my down-vote but the question is still not answerable in its current form.

Comment: Some new improvements to my initial question.

Comment: @domi: Just an… observation:  you're using `xelatex` or `lualatex` since you load …`fontspec`. They expect the source file to be `utf8` encoded, not `applemac`. Anyway, for portability, one should not  use `applemac` any more these days.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You also could do that with the `ntheorem` package: it has a `\theoremindent` length,and you can define an `observ` theorem structure in the `break` style.
Here is a possibility; I had to redefine the `break` style in order to ensure indentation for the first paragraph. If you don't want such indentation, there's nothing to redefine.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,footinclude=true,twoside,headinclude=true]{scrbook}
\usepackage[parts,pdfspacing,dottedtoc]{classicthesis}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[frenchb]{babel}
\setmainfont{Minion Pro}
\usepackage[marginparsep=8pt,left=3.5cm,right=3.5cm,top=3cm,bottom=3cm]{geometry}


\usepackage{ntheorem}
\theoremindent = 3em
\theorempreskip\medskipamount
\theorempostskip\medskipamount
\theoremstyle{break}
\theoremheaderfont{\itshape}
\theorembodyfont{\normalfont}
\makeatletter
\renewtheoremstyle{break}%
 {\item[\rlap{\vbox{\hbox{\hskip\labelsep \theorem@headerfont
 ##1\ ##2\theorem@separator}\hbox{\strut}}}]\hskip\parindent}%
 {\item[\rlap{\vbox{\hbox{\hskip\labelsep \theorem@headerfont
 ##1\ ##2\ (##3)\theorem@separator}\hbox{\strut}}}]\hskip\parindent}
\makeatother
\newtheorem{observ}{Observation}

    \begin{document}

A repetitive text a repetitive text a repetitive text a repetitive text a repetitive text a repetitive text a repetitive text a repetitive text a repetitive text.
   \begin{observ}
    This is my text. This my text This is my text. This my text This is my text. This my text This is my text. This my text This is my text. This my text. This my text This is my text. This my text This is my text. This my text.

    This is my text. This my text This is my text. This my text This is my text. This my text This is my text. This my text This is my text. This my text. This my text This is my text. This my text This is my text. This my text.
   \end{observ}
 Another no less repetitive text. Another no less repetitive text. Another no less repetitive text. Another no less repetitive text. Another no less repetitive text.

    \end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: It's (nearly) perfect ! Could it be possible to insert a space just before the Observation paragraph begins ? In this case, I would have exactly what I'm looking for. But I don't want to do that by using \\. Is there a specific rule ?

Answer (score 2):

Create your own environment to set things the way you want.

Below I've used `adjustwidth` (from [`changepage`](http://ctan.org/pkg/changepage)) to set a quotation-like environment called `observation`. The `observation` title follows a counter that you can reference using `\label`-`\ref`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}% Just for this example

\usepackage{changepage,lipsum}

\newcounter{observation}
\newenvironment{observation}
  {\par\medskip
   \begin{adjustwidth}{2em}{2em}
     \setlength{\parindent}{1.5em}% \parindent for Observations
     \small% Font changes (if any)
     \refstepcounter{observation}% Increment counter
     \hspace*{\parindent}% Indent Observation title
     Observation~\theobservation% Print Observation title
    \par\nobreak\smallskip}%
  {\end{adjustwidth}\medskip}
\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]

\begin{observation}
  \lipsum[2-3]
\end{observation}

\lipsum[4]

\begin{observation}
  \lipsum[5]
\end{observation}

\begin{observation}
  \lipsum[6]
\end{observation}

\lipsum[7]

\begin{observation}
  \lipsum[8-10]
\end{observation}

\lipsum[11]

\end{document}
```

You can adjust the `\parindent` (`1.5em`) and `adjustwidth` indents (`2em`) to suit your needs. The same goes for any font adjustments (`\small` in this case).

Comment: It works well ! In the case it could be possible, can I align on the right margin the paragraph called "observation" ?

Comment: @domi: If you want the right-margin of the `observation` environment to be flush with the remainder of the text, use `\begin{adjustwidth}{2em}{0pt}` in the definition.